# How to center two text views inside a circle layout in Android Studio?

Tags: android, css, xml, android-studio, android-layout

**What I have done:** I have added a verticle linear layout in the middle so that I can align text views one after another. But when I tried to center them there behaviors are strange. They appear as below. It seems every component is more attached to the top instead of the center.

[image]

**What I'm looking for:** I want to center two text views (DAY And DATE) followed by one another inside a circle. My main layout is a linear layout. I want all the groups of content inside the circle to be in the middle of the outer layout.

I would really appreciate any suggestion on this. Thank you!

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="385dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="DAY"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="DATE" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

Use:
      android:layout_gravity="center" for the Linear Layout which contains the two textviews.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!  I also changed `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" > android:gravity="center"` in outer layout to make circle in the center of the whole layout too.